# How to do conditional calculations on Pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hi my dataframe looks like this

| Date | Vehicle No. | Qauntity | CaO | MgO | SiO2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2021 | AB-1234 | 50.9 | 28.35 | 18.35 | 5.59 |
| 02.01.2021 | CD-1234 | 47.8 | 27.99 | 18.12 | 5.80 |
| 03.01.2021 | AB-1234 | 48.8 | 26.50 | 17.20 | 6.50 |
| 04.01.2021 | CD-1234 | 51.2 | 28.90 | 16.90 | 6.20 |

I am looking for a method to add new columns for deductions of CaO and MgO if they are below 28, 18 respectively and SiO2 if above 6.
I also have to deduct at double the rate below a certain threshold.
E.g. if CaO is below 28, I want the new column value to be

```
df["Quantity"] * ((28-df["CaO"])/0.1) * (0.3*df["Price"])/100
```

if CaO is below 17 then new column value should be

```
df["Quantity"] * ((28-df["CaO"])/0.1) * (0.6 * df["Price"])/100
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You can use `apply`

**Pseudo-code:**

```
def func(row):
    row['CaO'] = (np.where(row['CaO']<28, row["Quantity"] * ((28-row["CaO"])/0.1) * (0.3)/100, row.CaO))
    return row

df[['CaO', 'MgO', 'Quantity']] = df[['CaO', 'MgO', 'Quantity']].apply(func,axis=1)
```

Comment: I would try this. btw i want to add new columns for deductions not replace the values of the existing columns.

Comment: @SourabhPatel: You can create new columns also. Approach will be the same.

Comment: i tried this `df["UnderSize Ded"] = np.where(df["Undersize"] > 45, ((df["Undersize"]-30)/0.1)*(0.003*df["Price"])*df["Quantity"],np.where(df["Undersize"] > 30,
                      ((df["Undersize"]-30)/0.1)*(0.001*df["Price"])*df["Quantity"],0))`
and it worked perfectly

Comment: I however have a new problem i am trying to pick up quantity from a df in which only vehicle no. is mentioned to another dataframe where the same vehicle no is mentioned with a diffrent date generally 1 day after the date in the first dataframe.
i want to check if the vehicle no is same in both df and if the difference between dates is less <= 2 then i want to attribute the quantity from one df to the second df in the row with the same vehicle no.
any idea how can i aceive this.
till now i have tried df.merge but it messes up the dates.
any solutions.
thanks apply works as expected

Comment: @SourabhPatel: Can you asked separate question with sample df and the expected output?

Comment: Sure I'll post a new question today

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: first identify the rows and then add the calculated values

Eg. if CaO is below 28:

```
# Identify rows
bool_CaO_below_28 = df["CaO"] < 28

# Initialize column
df["new_columns"] = None

# Add new values
df.loc[bool_CaO_below_28, "new_columns"] = df.loc[bool_CaO_below_28, "Quantity"] * ((28-df.loc[bool_CaO_below_28,"CaO"])/0.1) * (0.3*df.loc[bool_CaO_below_28,"Price"])/100
```